# Can I pass a variable value into BigQuery from R using the bigrquery package?

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I have a simple R program that runs a query against several tables in bigquery with a date parameter.  My preference would be to declare the parameter value once and have it passed into the sql statement dynamically rather than update each query manually.

```
library(bigrquery)
library(dplyr)

project <- "myproject"
minDate <- "11-13-15"

myResults <- query_exec('select attribute list from [projectname.tablename]
         where controlDate > "11-13-15";',project = project)
```

How can I replace the hard code date with my minDate value?

Thanks,

Comment: `?paste` and `?sprintf` should help ...

Comment: and there are times I can't find my glasses on my head.  You're right, I can use paste to build the statement then pass the statement in.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the solution @CL. provided as a comment in the form of an answer, so that the question won't look unanswered:

> ?paste and ?sprintf should help